# Delegation of contact picker doesn't set properly

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to pick contact number from address book, and while I am trying to revamp the logics for it, it failed to pick the address book, instead, when I click the number, it's calling that number. The delegation doesn't get called while I try to select the number.

The code below is quite long though, but I am trying to describe everything (omitting unrelated codes), so you get the idea of the problem.

So, the complicated things is, I have a **HomeViewController**, which I do set all the data from a helper called **HomeHelper** (a UIView with UITableView). I do add a UITableViewCell from a view called **WidgetView**, and the data is being set from **WidgetHelper**. WidgetHelper will load a UITableViewCell called **WidgetProductAHelper** (and the view called WidgetProductAView).

WidgetProductAView contains an Image Button and when I click the button, it should show the Contact Picker. I try to separate the logic to a new class called **AddressBookHelper**, so I can use this everywhere without any redundancy. It does succeed to show the address book, but when I try to click one of them, it will redirected to the detail contact screen instead of calling **peoplePickerNavigationController's** method. I have set the delegation for that but still doesn't work.

This things does work when I try to write them in one class only. What could be wrong? Please help to figure out, I suspect there is some improper implementation on using helpers but could't figure that out. Thanks.

**HomeViewController.swift**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var dataSource : UITableViewDataSource?
    var delegate : UITableViewDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //
        let helper = HomeHelper()

        helper.homeViewController = self

        dataSource = helper
        delegate = helper

        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = delegate
    }

}
```

**HomeHelper.swift**

```
class HomeHelper: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, WidgetViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WidgetView", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        if let customView = cell.customView as? WidgetView {
            let helper = WidgetHelper()
            customView.helperDataSource = helper
            customView.helperDelegate = helper
            customView.delegate = self
            helper.controller = customView

            customView.initCell()

            return cell
        }
    }

    // MARK: - WidgetViewDelegate

    func presentOnHome(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {
        self.homeViewController?.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

}
```

**WidgetView.swift**

```
protocol WidgetViewDelegate {
    func presentOnHome(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)?)
}

class WidgetView: NSObject {

    var delegate: WidgetViewDelegate?

    var helperDataSource: WidgetViewHelperDataSource?
    var helperDelegate: WidgetViewHelperDelegate?

    func initCell() {
        //
        tableView.dataSource = helperDataSource
        tableView.delegate = helperDelegate
    }

    func presentOnHome(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)?) {
        delegate?.presentOnHome(viewControllerToPresent, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

}
```

**WidgetHelper.swift**

```
class WidgetHelper: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, WidgetProductAHelperDelegate {

    var controller: WidgetView?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WidgetProductAView", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        if let customView = cell.customView as? WidgetProductAHelper {
            customView.parentHelper = self
            customView.delegate = self
            customView.initCell()

            return cell
        }
    }

    // MARK: - WidgetProductAHelperDelegate

    func presentOnHome(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {
        self.homeViewController?.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

}
```

**WidgetProductAHelper.swift**

```
protocol WidgetProductAHelperDelegate {
    func presentOnHome(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)?)
}

class WidgetProductAHelper: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var contactImageButton: UIButton!

    var parentHelper: WidgetHelper?
    var delegate: WidgetProductAHelperDelegate?

}

func initCell() {
    //
    contactImageButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    contactImageButton.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(WidgetProductAHelper.contactImageButtonTapped(_:))))
}

func contactImageButtonTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let addressBookHelper = AddressBookHelper()
    addressBookHelper.contactImageButton = contactImageButton
    addressBookHelper.completion = { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .presentOnHome(let viewControllerToPresent) :
            self.parentHelper?.presentOnHome(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)

            break
        }
    }
    addressBookHelper.addressBookButtonTapped()
}
```

**AddressBookHelper.swift**

As you see on below code, I have set the delegate of CNPicker to the class, but doesn't call the delegate's method. For another things like displayErrorMessage() and displayPromptForAddressBookRequestAccess(), it works well on showing the pop-up.

```
enum AddressBookActionResult {
    case presentOnHome(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController)
}

class AddressBookHelper: NSObject, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    var completion: ((AddressBookActionResult) -> ())?

    var contactImageButton: UIButton?

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    var CNPicker: CNContactPickerViewController {
        return CNContactPickerViewController()
    }

    func addressBookButtonTapped() {
        switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) {
        case .denied, .restricted:
            // displayErrorMessage()
            break
        case .authorized:
            openUserAddressBook()
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            // displayPromptForAddressBookRequestAccess()
            break
        }
    }

    func openUserAddressBook() {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            CNPicker.delegate = self
            completion?(.presentOnHome(viewControllerToPresent: CNPicker))
        }
    }


    // MARK: - CNContactPickerDelegate

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
        // This method doesn't get called
        //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this function:

```
func openUserAddressBook() {
        let CNPicker: CNContactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
        CNPicker.delegate = self
        completion?(.presentOnHome(viewControllerToPresent: CNPicker))
    }
```

You're creating the `CNPicker` within that function and as soon as it *exits* the `openUserAddressBook` function, `CNPicker` gets released.

It would be better to make `CNPicker` a property that lives at the top of your AddressBookHelper.

e.g.:

```
class AddressBookHelper: NSObject, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    // create CNContactPickerViewController once and only once
    let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()

    var completion: ((AddressBookActionResult) -> ())?

    override init()
    {
        super.init()

        // and set the delegate of the picker to this Helper class
        self.cnPicker.delegate = self
    }

    func openUserAddressBook() {
        completion?(.presentOnHome(viewControllerToPresent: self.cnPicker))
    }

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController,
                   didSelect contact: CNContact)
    {
        print("selected a contact!")
    }

    // and other delegate methods can be implemented and they
    // will be called...

}
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Dautermann, thank you so much, but it still doesn't work for me. I have updated the question for your reference.

Comment: The thing you're doing now, a ` return CNContactPickerViewController()` to each call of the `CNPicker` property, ***creates*** a new CNContactPickerViewController each and every time it's referenced.  You need to create the CNContactPickerViewController once and then set it to a property and it'll stick around.

Answer (score 0):

CNContactPickerDelegate doesn't have method

```
 func peoplePickerNavigationController(_ peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord) {
        // This method doesn't get called
        //...
 }
```

it has instead

```
func contactPicker(CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect: CNContact)
Called after a contact has been selected by the user.
```

you can see full list of delegate's methods here 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactpickerdelegate

Comment: Hi @Sergnsk, whoops sorry, I just updated the code, I copied the wrong code from my project, thanks for noticing ;(